# How do I write back to a text file with StringBuilder?

Tags: c#

Currently my code isn't inserting additional data and instead is overwriting the data in my test file.

Code Snippet follows:

```
string path = @"C:\\test.txt"; // <==NEW
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, Filemode.Open, FileAccess.Write)); // <==NEW
StringBuilder Editions = new StringBuilder(400);



Editions.Insert(0, "0");
Editions.Insert(1, "0");
//Editions.Remove(9, 14);
//Editions.Insert(11, "R");
//Editions.Insert(12, "M");
//Editions.Insert(13, "A");
//Editions.Insert(14, "L");
//Editions.Insert(15, "L");
//Editions.Insert(16, " ");
//Editions.Insert(17, " ");
//Editions.Insert(18, " ");
//Editions.Insert(193, "C");
//Editions.Insert(194, "L");
sw.Write(Editions.ToString()); // <== NEW
sw.Flush(); // <== NEW
sw.Close(); // <== NEW
```

Comment: you need to open file for Append :)

Comment: Alright, how would I go about doing so?
    Because using FileMode.Append causes my edits to be added to the end of the file instead of where I actually need them to be placed.

Comment: Filemode.Open - >  Filemode.Append :) see my answer

Comment: Why not try to use File.AppendAllText...??

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add more data, you need to open your file in `Append` mode

```
@"C:\\test.txt"; // <==NEW
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, Filemode.Append, FileAccess.Write)); // <==NEW
StringBuilder Editions = new StringBuilder(400);


Editions.Insert(0, "0");
Editions.Insert(1, "0");
//Editions.Remove(9, 14);
//Editions.Insert(11, "R");
//Editions.Insert(12, "M");
//Editions.Insert(13, "A");
//Editions.Insert(14, "L");
//Editions.Insert(15, "L");
//Editions.Insert(16, " ");
//Editions.Insert(17, " ");
//Editions.Insert(18, " ");
//Editions.Insert(193, "C");
//Editions.Insert(194, "L");
sw.Write(Editions.ToString()); // <== NEW
sw.Flush(); // <== NEW
sw.Close(); // <== NEW
```

More information - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Quoting from MSDN : Append

> Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append
>   permission. FileMode.Append can be used only in conjunction with
>   FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek to a position before the end of the
>   file throws an IOException exception, and any attempt to read fails
>   and throws a NotSupportedException exception.

Furthermore - When you using Insert be careful about "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" .!! [READ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s24x24x5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: FileMode.Append causes my edits to be added to the end of the file instead of where I need them to be placed.

Comment: IMO your question need to further improve  then :)